# What does the _LH suffix mean in the Windows API?

Tags: winapi

In the Windows API there is a structure called [`IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_LH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_addresses_lh).

What does the `_LH` suffix indicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_LH` suffix indicates that the API is valid for Windows Vista or later. `LH` is short for "Longhorn", which was the code name for Windows Vista.

You may see other suffixes such as:

- `_W2K`: Windows 2000
- `_W2KSP1`: Windows 2000 SP1
- `_XP`: Windows XP or later

Answer (score 1):

Per the [`IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_addresses_lh):

> The size of the **IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES** structure changed on Windows XP with SP1 and later. The size of the **IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES** structure also changed on Windows Vista and later. The size of the **IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES** structure also changed on Windows Vista with SP1 and later and on Windows Server 2008 and later. The **Length** member should be used to determine which version of the **IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES** structure is being used.
>
> ...
>
> In the Windows SDK, the version of the structure for use on Windows Vista and later is defined as **IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_LH**. In the Microsoft Windows Software Development Kit (SDK), the version of this structure to be used on earlier systems including Windows XP with SP1 and later is defined as **IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_XP**. When compiling an application if the target platform is Windows Vista and later (`NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_LONGHORN`, `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600`, or `WINVER >= 0x0600`), the **IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_LH** structure is typedefed to the **IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES** structure. When compiling an application if the target platform is not Windows Vista and later, the **IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_XP** structure is typedefed to the **IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES** structure.